# VUE Router not working with two Electron BrowserWindows

Tags: electron, vuejs2, vue-router

I’m trying to create an app with two BrowserWindows using the same Vue App with vue-router, but the router aren’t working. I’m always receiving error ‘Cannot GET /’ for the second route.

**main\index.js**

```
var mainURL = `http://localhost:9080/`
var secondURL = `http://localhost:9080/page2`

function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 600,
    width: 800
  })
  mainWindow.loadURL(mainURL)
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null
  })

  secondWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 600,
    width: 800
  })
  secondWindow.loadURL(secondURL)
  secondWindow.on('closed', () => {
    secondWindow = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

**routes.js**

```
export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'landing-page',
    component: require('components/LandingPageView')
  },
  {
    path: '/page2',
    name: 'landing-page2',
    component: require('components/LandingPageView2')
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    redirect: '/'
  }
]
```

Testing code: https://github.com/melquic/vue-two-windows.git

Error print screen:

[image]

Thank you for help!
Best.

Comment: You can find the details of routing issue of vuejs from here
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL needs to be http://localhost:9080/#/page2 in order to make this work.