# Electron Vue after refresh page return: Cannot GET /url

Tags: vue.js, electron

I installed electron with vue (used this [instruction](https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-electron/)). I have routes file:

```
import Home from '../components/views/Home.vue';
import Knowledge from '../components/views/Knowledge.vue';

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/knowledge',
        name: 'Knowledge',
        component: Knowledge
    }
];

export default routes;
```

And menu.vue file:

```
<a @click="$router.push({ name: 'Home' })">Home</a>
<a @click="$router.push({ name: 'Knowledge' })">Knowledge</a>
```

when I click to Knowledge or Home components load correctly, but when I am in component 'Knowledge' and click `Ctrl + R` Electron returns this error:

> Cannot GET /knowledge

and 3 times this same error in the console:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Either the
>   'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-tNDGcuur+Xq1hWGosyhxNn/LdCiCH7CeKGodlT3JvPg='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that
>   'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
>   fallback

But when I reload electron in Home component it does not return any error

Answer (score 2):

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43814083/6678345). Just I need add `#` to `path`:

```
{
    path: '/#/knowledge',
    name: 'Knowledge',
    component: Knowledge
},
```

Comment: If you don't use 'mode: "history"' then you won't have to add /#/ before each routing. 
after the built it will automatically add # before each routing. if you want to use 'mode: "history"' then you might need to do some configuration change in your server. Please find the link for details https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations